# How to fetch the values from list, if list contains values as array in java

Tags: java

How to fetch the values from list, if list contains values as array in java. For example:

```
testList = [[Item 1, Item 2, Item 6]]
```

now the size 1, while trying with `testList.get(0);` the output is `[Item 1, Item 2, Item 6]`. But I would like to fetch the individual values like:

```
Item 1,
Item 2,
Item 3
```

How to do this?

Comment: You appear to have a two dimensional array composed by an ArrayList and an array. You have to fetch them all with two nested loops (for, for-each, while, iterator, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can access a list using `.get(index)`:

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
list.add("Item 1");

System.out.println(list.get(0)); //Item 1
```

You can access an array using `[index]`:

```
String[] array = new String[] {"Item 1"};

System.out.println(array[0]); // Item 1
```

And so you can access any nested list/array, using the correct access operator(-concatenation):

```
List<String[]> list = new LinkedList<String[]>();

list.add(new String[] {"Item 1"});
list.add(new String[] {"Item 2"});

System.out.println(list.get(0)[0]); // Item 1
```

Comment: While trying with this i got the same O/P as array,....sItems1000.get(0)[0]-------- [Item 1, Item 2, Item 6]

Comment: @kamal8878 Because your "List" contains an "Array" that contains an "Array". So you would need to use `list.get(0)[0][0]` for `Item 1` (note the doubled `[` and `]` within your dump - that's an array within an array) (I'm not sure about your markup provided - the example seems different than the verbal description)

Comment: im getting compile time error while trying with this.

Comment: @kamal8878 please provide the code, that builds up the collection. `testList = [[Item 1, Item 2, Item 6]]` is no valid notation and does not allow to reconstruct the original layout. It seems like an `array` of three values within an `array` of one value (if arrays std. `toString()` has been used) - but that does not show where your mentioned `List` is located at.

Comment: List<String> sItems100 = new ArrayList<String>();
.
:
sItems100.add(String.valueOf(listsALL.get(3)));
:
:
(listsALL - is an nested arraylist , 
while fetching the values from nested arraylist itself the values are array.)

when getting the value from sItems100.get(0) the O/P is
[[Item 1, Item 2, Item 6]]